# How to grant access only to our website to be able call .php files?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from lamtakam.test
    Allow from lamtakam.com
</Files>
```

It doesn't let others call a `.php` file on my server. It was working well until I've migrated to another server. As I said, recently I've changed my server and in the new server, Crons don't work: (since when it run, it gets 403 Forbbiden error)

```
curl https://lamtakam.com/whatever.php
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Noted that when I remove `Deny from all` in `.htaccess` file, it works well.

Comment: That is Apache 2.2 syntax, did you try Apache 2.4 syntax. I would assume the new Server is using Apache 2.4 and may well by now have removed the 2.2 compatability module

Comment: Which version of Apache you are using?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada 2.4.29

Comment: try order allow,deny
<Files *.php>
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from lamtakam.test
    Allow from lamtakam.com
</Files>

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the first place to look for clues is the difference between your old and your new server. It might be that the new server is running Apache 2.4? The syntax has changed, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

This

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

should now be

```
Require all denied
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the new syntax of this? `Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all`

Comment: @MartinAJ Why don't you simply take a look into the documentation of the tool you are using?

Comment: @arkascha I found asked one in the [doucmentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html). But not something for multiple-`Allow` like this: `Order Deny,Allow Deny from all Allow from ::1 Allow from lamtakam.test`

Comment: Yes, it is in there: `Require not host phishers.example.com moreidiots.example`... You see it is a concatenation? Just leave away the negation.   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: @arkascha Well thanks for the link you provided. It gave some clues to me. Just I didn't understand what you mean by "leave away" (when there is **concatenation**).  How should it be look like `Allow from site1.com Deny from site2.com` ?

Comment: Read the deprecation warning in the red box: the `Allow` directives and similar should not be used any more. Instead use the `Require` directive as shown. What I tried to point out to you is that you can simply concatenate hosts or domains in a single directive. So here something like `Require host ::1 lamtakam.test lamtakam.com`.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just out of curiosity, is `::1` known as host or ip ? @arkascha

Comment: It is interpreted as an IP address, since it would be invalid as a host name.